# "Error opening SHP file" when loading from package data

Tags: r, rstudio

I want to shift some of my most commonly used shapefiles to github.  I have a [new package in development](https://github.com/geotheory/londonShapefiles).  It worked when built in RStudio, but when I pull the package from github and run it I get the error `"Error in getinfo.shape(filen) : Error opening SHP file"`.  When I look inside the package the shapefiles are in place in the `data` folder.  They're being called by individual functions, e.g.

```
load_lon = function(){
  require(maptools)
  lon <<- readShapePoly('data/london_outline_simple.shp', proj4string=CRS('+init=epsg:27700'))
}
```

Presumably this method means R is wrongly looking for subfolder 'data' in the working directory.  But I can't think how else to call them, as `data()` doesn't support shp.  Grateful for advice how to load them in.

Comment: You shouldn't be putting .shp files in the data folder.  http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages

Comment: Put the data somewhere like `$SOURCEDIR/ext/external` (in your sources) and then use the path returned by `system.file("external/shapfilename.shp", package="packagename")` to load it from your installed package. You'll find many examples in R's spatial packages, e.g. [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/raster/docs/intersect), where a shapefile is loaded using `p <- shapefile(system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster"))`.

Comment: @josh-obrien do you mean folder `/ext/external` within the project root folder?  `system.file(..)` is returning an empty string (although the function is reaching the right directory).  Using straight `/external` doesn't work either.  And when I looking in the package folder `external` isn't there..

Comment: @geotheory -- Sorry, I was in a rush and should have waited until I could take a moment longer to get the comment right! I meant that you should put it in `$SOURCEDIR/inst/external/` (not `$SOURCEDIR/ext/external/`). (Have a look at p. 14 of `RShowDoc("R-exts")` to learn that a source subdirectory named `inst` is treated specially, with its contents recursively copied into the installation directory. That's a very handy thing to know!)

Comment: Works! Many thanks.  Please copy as answer and I'll tick off.  Should fully read this documentation I know, I've been winging it so far without.

Comment: @geotheory -- Would you mind writing up the answer yourself, and (eventually) accepting it? I'll upvote the answer if you do. Thanks.

Comment: Not at all, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

In line with @josh-obrien's comment, the answer is to put data files in a subfolder of `inst`, whereupon they'll be compiled with the code when the package is built.  I've put the shapefiles in:

```
$SOURCEDIR/inst/external/
```

These are installed via functions such as:

```
load_lon = function(){
  require(maptools)
  path = system.file("external/london_outline_simple.shp", package="londonShapefiles")
  lon <<- readShapePoly(path, proj4string=CRS('+init=epsg:27700'))
}
```

Check out the [working github package](https://github.com/geotheory/londonShapefiles) for full working example.